# How to install haskell 8 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: haskell, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Haskell on ubuntu following the instructions on the Haskell platform website. But I ended up with version 7.10.3. How do I get Haskell 8 on Ubuntu?

Comment: What distribution of Haskell? GHC I suppose?

Comment: Check out https://www.haskellstack.org Stack will install the version of GHC needwd to build your project

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the de-facto standard for installing Haskell is now using [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/).

Here's the [official installation instructions](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#ubuntu).

Comment: The Ubuntu packages listed on that page are pretty outdated. I'd recommend following [the official installation instructions](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#ubuntu) instead.

Answer (score 16):

You can get GHC 8.0.2 from hvr's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc

To get the latest GHC run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hvr/ghc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ghc-8.0.2
```

The PPA also contains other tools that you might need such as `cabal`.

Comment: to run use: /opt/ghc/bin/ghc-8.0.2 or /opt/ghc/bin/ghci

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use stack follow [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/yantonov/10083524).

Maybe afterwards you want to install the following additional packages:

- alex
- happy
- haddock
- hlint
- pandoc

and more depending what you want to do.

If the library yout intstalle ghc, is in your path, you can the remove haskell-platform.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean GHC 8.* by “haskell 8”.

I just installed GHC 8.4.3, the current stable release, on Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 a week ago.

Just [download the binary](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_4_3.html#binaries), (I chose the `Linux (x86_64) - Debian 9` one, i.e. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.3/ghc-8.4.3-x86_64-deb9-linux.tar.xz) and follow the `INSTALL` file after unarchiving.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add to $PATH.

i.e.: `PATH=/opt/ghc/bin/:$PATH`

There you can find `ghc-8.6.2`, `ghc` binaries.

More info:
https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/blog/ghc-8.6.1-released
which points to a deeper info page: https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc